# Outlook 2007 Default Save Location

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2007, attachments

I opened an attachment in Outlook 2007 and saved it from there.
Now I cannot seem to find where this document was saved.

What is the default directory that Outlook saves files to ?
I'm working on Windows 7 if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you open file attachments that are considered safe, Outlook places these attachments in a subdirectory under the your `Temporary Internet Files` directory as an extra precaution. When Outlook first tries to use a temporary file, it examines the registry to determine whether or not the `TEMP OLK` folder has already been created. If yes, it uses the folder. If no, it creates a random folder then stores the path in the registry.

To find where it’s been created, open the Windows registry using `regedit.exe` and look for the Registry key `OutlookSecureTempFolder` using the MAP below:

[image]

For example:

```
C:\Users\Pmarcoen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.Outlook\XLCYUT3R
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally it will save to the last folder you saved something to. If that folder is missing it should use Documents folder. At least that's how it behaves on my PC.

Easiest thing to do however (and useful in all programs) is to just start saving it again and check what folder it is or copy path from Save dialog window.